# Simple jquery selector - selecting a button in a specific table

Tags: jquery

I want to select a `button` in a row of a `table` with `id="myid"` and `rel="myrel"`.  Here's what doesn't work:

`$(table.mytable tr button[rel=myrel])`.

I think the mistake is how I have selected the table ID?

Thank you :).

Comment: Can you add an id or a class to your button to make it easier on yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is:

```
$('table.mytable tr button[rel="myrel"]')
```

Newer versions of jquery handle the selection of attributes (like *rel*) with double quotes which is the new requirement now. But since you also have an id assigned to it, you can just use `$('#myid')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wrap your selector in quotes as it appears to work fine in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aqCeh/).

```
$("table.mytable tr button[rel=myrel]")
```